# MITライセンスのソフトウェアをフォークした場合のライセンス表記

Tags: github, mit-license, ライセンス

MITライセンスのソフトウェアをフォークし、改変し、やはりMITライセンスで配布する場合、フォーク元の著作権表記を残しておく必要はありますか？　またその場合、どのような表記が適切ですか？

「特に決まりはないが慣例ではこうなっている」といったご回答でもありがたいです。

Comment: タグ 'mit-license' を追加しました。

Comment: 改変後のソフトウェアは二次的著作物であり、原著作物（改変前のソフトウェア）、二次的著作物、両方の著作者の著作権表記が必要な気がしてきました。併記例を探してみます。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20427471 を見ると、並列的に記載するのが無難のようです。実例も見つかりました。
https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

フォーク、改変しても大本のライセンス保持者は変わりません

自身が、フォーク、改変した部分を記載して追記するのは構わないですが、元の記載を削除するのは違反となるはずです