# MITライセンスで[再配布]の場合の表記例

Tags: github, ライセンス, mit-license

Githubにて、他人の「MITラインセンス」のソースコードをダウンロードし、自分で改版した後、再度「MITライセンス」として自分のGithubレポジトリに公開する場合についてご教授ください。

**① ソースコードの先頭に付与する「ライセンス表記」例を教えてください。**

**② Githubにアップロードする「LICENSE」ファイルの記入例を教えてください。**

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 過去に類似質問がありますのでこちらも参考に: [MITライセンスのソフトウェアをフォークした場合のライセンス表記](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/3040)

Comment: ありがとうございます。その類似質問を確認した上で、質問させていただいております。わかりずらかったので、①と②の例を記載いただけると、より全ての方に役に立つかと思いまして。

Answer (score 2):

類似質問の回答では、2段で記載するとのことでした。

**①の例**

```
Copyright (c) 2013 Chris Strutton
<Your own copyright notice here, 
perhaps with link to original project and description of own contributions>

Copyright (c) 2013 Michel Nemnom
Permission is hereby granted, ... (the balance of the existing licence text)
```

訳

```
Copyright (c) 2019 自分の名前
<自身の著作権表示を記載し、オリジナルプロジェクトのURLと貢献度を説明する？>

Copyright (c) 2013 オリジナルの人の名前
<オリジナルの著作権表示を記載>
```

**②の例**

https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE

こちらも2段にして、1段目の最後に以下のような注釈を追加されているようです。

```
<The major design pattern of this plugin was abstracted
from Peter Jackson's VoteFu, which is subject to the same license.
Here is the original copyright notice for VoteFu:>
```

Google翻訳

```
<このプラグインの主要な設計パターンは、同じライセンスの対象である
Peter JacksonのVoteFuから抽象化されました。
以下は、VoteFuの元の著作権表示です。>
```

Answer (score 0):

部分回答になりますが、LICENSEファイルの記入例(ひな型)は以下のリンク先にあります。

[MIT License | Choose a License](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/)

GitHub リポジトリへのライセンスの適用については、ヘルプも参照してください。

[リポジトリのライセンス - GitHub ヘルプ](https://help.github.com/ja/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository)

Comment: 他人のコードを自分で改版した場合の表記例を求めております。記述されたリンク先には載ってません。